# Android listview adapter get item id without setting it

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and I have Adapter - `ListView` model to display array.

I set it's value's so:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.bank_list,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_central_office_address }, new int[] {
                        R.id.bank_name, R.id.central_office_address});

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BankExchangersListActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("Bank_id", TAG_ID);
                startActivity(in);
            }

        });
```

I get my values from JSON:

```
url = "http://192.168.1.4:3000/banks.json";
        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            banks = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BANKS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < banks.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = banks.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String central_office_address = c.getString(TAG_central_office_address);
                // Phone number is agin JSON Object


                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_central_office_address, name);


                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As you can see in JSON I have ID field, but i didn't set it in `ListView`. For next query I click on `ListView` element and go to other activity, but I need to get `TAG_ID` of this element. Maybe I did something wrong? How to get element's `TAG_ID` on which I click, without displaying it on `ListView`?

JUST send tag_id of clicked item!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position` parameter of the `onItemClick` method gives the index of the selected item in the adapted list. So you can find the TAG_ID of the original item at

```
((Map<String, String>) adapter.getItem(position)).get(TAG_ID)
```

make the adapter final so that you can reference it inside the listener:

```
final ListAdapter adapter = ...
```

Comment: where do you mean to write that/

Comment: becouse now helper say me to write getItem method

Comment: In the SimpleAdapter: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29

Comment: hm ... Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BankExchangersListActivity.class);
             String a = ((Map<String, String>) getItem(position)).get(TAG_ID);
                in.putExtra("Bank_id", TAG_ID);
                startActivity(in);  didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you.
 you can get `Postion` of  `ListSelectedItemId`  and passed it with `Intent`and get it in `SecondActivity` now Here get `FirstActivity` `HashMap` with define it `static`

now use foreachloop to get all values from  `HashMap`   like

```
public static void printMap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());            
    }
}
```

now with specific position of `ListSelectedItemId` you can get values from currentList

or like

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: now with specific position of ListSelectedItemId you can get values from currentList   how to get it?

Comment: if you need on sameActivity you can get in Listview ItemSelect Method using above code

Comment: else need to pass all Hasmap in SecondActivity

Comment: sorry for my "nubbism", i need it on second activity, i pass it from first so in.putExtra("Bank_id", TAG_ID);, but i didn't understand you where in my code above to paste it? )

Comment: just make it public static HasMap map

Comment: and get i Second Activity Like HasMap mlist = FirstAct.map;

Comment: Like  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mcontactList = FirstActivity.contactList

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27934/discussion-between-ankitmakwana-and-brabertaser1992)

Comment: then i get all array, but how get only one integer value? just id tag_id without any array's final... etc... just in first get listview tag_id